# How to get the Express Session variable in all the handlebars pages, right now i have render it each time, i want it to be done once only

Tags: node.js, session, handlebars.js

How to get the Express Session variable in all the handlebars pages, right now i have render it each time, i want it to be done once only and access in from the handlebar page.

index.js

```
app.post('/first',function(req,res){
var session = require('express-session');
req.session.fullname =Email;
res.render('first',
{Email:req.session.fullname,arrayofpromotions:arrayofpromotion,layout:false});
```

first.handlebars

```
 <li><a href="#"> {{#if Email}} Welcome {{ Email }}{{/if}}</a></li>
```

When the page is requested from /first url, i can read the session variable, as i have rendered it, but not from other pages, i want the variable available without rendering it. So that i can read the session variables from some other pages also.

Like if i go to /second also the req.session.fullname should contain value.

I read some other answers on stackoverflow but i didnt get the exact solutions for it. Please help.

Comment: I guess that you are not properly storing or managing sessions in express please have a look [link](https://lockmedown.com/securing-node-js-managing-sessions-express-js/) this might help.

Answer (score 6):

### Session in Handlebars :

```
    // app.js
    app.use(session(options));
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        res.locals.session = req.session;
        next();
    });
```

on `handlebars` template use this as following : `{{ session.SOMETHING_THAT_YOU_ASSIGNED }}`

Comment: would res.locals not be better so it is only assigned for the request and won't be accidentally assigned to other concurrent users?